# Hpple not able to parse HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, libxml2, hpple

I'm using Hpple to parse HTML and it seems that it doesn't recognize it is actually XML, which it should (XCode debugger shows this variable `isXML = (BOOL) NO` and it doesn't collect any data). How do I fix this?

This is my code (they're may be other bugs as well). the parse method/function is called first with `[ListParser parse:@"http://www.fanfiction.net/book/Harry-Potter/" at:@"//div[@=\"class\"]"];`:

```
@interface ListParser () //private
+ (NSArray*) getNodeListAt: (NSURL*) page inside: (NSString*) page;
+ (NSDictionary*) getNodeData: (TFHppleElement*) node;
+ (void) addMiniListData: (NSString*) list to: (NSMutableDictionary*) dict;
@end


@implementation ListParser

+ (NSArray*) getNodeListAt: (NSURL*) page inside: (NSString*) path { // "//div[@class"z-list"]"
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: page];
    TFHpple *listparser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data]; //WHERE CODE SEEMS TO STOP TO WORK
    NSArray *done = [listparser searchWithXPathQuery: path];
    return done;
}

+ (void) addMiniListData: (NSString*) list to: (NSMutableDictionary*) dict{
    NSArray *parts = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];

    for(NSString* p in parts){
        NSArray* two = [p componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
        [dict setObject:[two objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[two objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

+ (NSDictionary*) getNodeData: (TFHppleElement*) node{
    NSMutableDictionary* data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [data setObject:[[[node firstChild] firstChild] objectForKey:@"href"] forKey:@"Image"];
    [data setObject:[[node firstChild] text] forKey:@"Title"];
    [data setObject:[[[[node firstChild] children] objectAtIndex:2] text] forKey:@"By"];
    [data setObject:[[[[node firstChild] childrenWithClassName:@"z-indent"] objectAtIndex:0] text] forKey:@"Summery"];
    [self addMiniListData:[[[[[[node firstChild] childrenWithClassName:@"z-indent"] objectAtIndex:0] childrenWithClassName:@"z-padtop2"] objectAtIndex:0] text] to: data];

    return data;
}

+(NSArray*) parse: (NSString*) address at: (NSString*) path{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:address];
    NSArray* list = [self getNodeListAt:url inside:path];
    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (TFHppleElement* e in list) {
        [data addObject:[self getNodeData:e]];
    }
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: data];
}

@end
```

Here's a link to the tutorials I was following: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: @nneonneo I'm aware, but allegedly it's suppose to work for both. At least according to its website and several tutorials it says it will recognize HTML as XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse XML with a `TFHpple`, you should tell it that you're doing so. You're calling `+hppleWithHTMLData:`. If you read the implementation of this method, you will see that it sets `isXML` to `NO`. Instead, use the `hppleWithXMLData:` method.